# Netlogo: How do I assign patches with one color to an agentset?

Tags: netlogo, patch, modeling, agent-based-modeling

I have patches of yellow and blue color. I wanted to assign all patches with color blue to an agentset *workspaces*.

This is what I tried.

> set  patches with [pcolor = blue] workspaces

However, I'm getting an error saying `This isn't something you can use 'set' on`. How do I solve this?

Also how do I declare the agent-set? I have initialized *workspaces* in globals now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
set workspaces patches with [pcolor = blue]
```